# Efficient way to copy specific keys

Tags: php, arrays, copy

I want to copy elements of specific indices/keys from one php array to another. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740160/php-array-copy-certain-keys-built-in-functions-nested-loop-performance) post and tried the following:

```
$a1=array(10,15,20,25,30);
$indices=array(2,4);
$result=array_intersect_key($a1,array_flip($indices));
print_r($result);
```

But my result is like this

```
Array ( [2] => 20 [4] => 30 )
```

I want the keys in the new array to start from `[0]`. ie., I want the result to be

```
Array ( [0] => 20 [1] => 30 )
```

I looked at `array_combine()` but is there any other efficient way to do this whole process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_values()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to get just the array values of the returned array from `array_intersect_key()`.

```
$result=array_values(array_intersect_key($a1,array_flip($indices)));
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NSgtQP)

Comment: I admit i like the solution, i'd had probably done it with a 2-line foreach in a hurry, lol

Comment: It's easy to forget that PHP has a ton of array functions that can be combined to do *almost* anything.

Comment: I know, but sometimes when you're in a hurry to get something done you chose the easy way. Performance wise, i honestly don't know which is faster, combining 2 functions or a foreach.

Comment: @ied3vil According to this post, functions are faster - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740160/php-array-copy-certain-keys-built-in-functions-nested-loop-performance

Answer (score 2):

If you have PHP5.3 or better, you could also use [`array_walk_recursive()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) with a closure:

```
$array = [10,15,20,25,30];
$indices = [2, 4];
array_walk_recursive($array, function($value, $index) use(&$array, $indices)
                             {
                                 if(!in_array($index, $indices))
                                     unset($array[$index]);
                             });
return array_values($array);
```

**Edit**:

> But is this more efficient than the previous solution?

Not really, no. Testing our original solutions, plus these two foreach solutions:

**Foreach 1**

```
function($array, $indices)
{
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
        if(!in_array($key, $indices))
            unset($array[$key]);
    return array_values($array);
}
```

**Foreach 2**

```
function($array, $indices)
{
    $newArray = [];
    foreach($indices as $index)
        $newArray[] = $array[$index];
    return $newArray;
}
```

I found the second foreach to be fastest:

1. Foreach 2- 0.0000069141387939453125s
2. John Conde- 0.000010967254638671875s
3. Foreach 1- 0.0000188350677490234375s
4. Mine-  0.000031948089599609375

[As an image](http://i110.photobucket.com/albums/n92/General-Jazza/testPHP2_zpsc5f7c28b.png).

Comment: But is this more efficient than the previous solution?

Comment: @Dinesh No, but I've tested and if speed is the only concern, foreach is definitely the fastest. (See edits)

Comment: So Foreach 2 is the fastest? Does it depend on the server?

Comment: @Dinesh There may be slight differences but it's definitely the fastest for me. Do some testing with [`microtime(true);`](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)

Comment: But why is there so much difference compared to here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740160/php-array-copy-certain-keys-built-in-functions-nested-loop-performance

Comment: @Dinesh Because he's using 20,0000 items and 10,000 keys instead of 5 items and 2 keys

Comment: @Dinesh Use whatever is the easiest for you to maintain. No one solution is significantly faster then another so worrying about that would be an unnecessary micro-optimization.